# Force an object field to having only certain values which are inherited from parent class

Tags: java, enums, field, limit

I have abstract class `Pet` with abstract method `feed(...)`. The method must take only on of certain three types of food (DRY, WET or RAW). These can be String type as I use them only as indicators in SWITCH in later logic. Also I have two subclasses `Cat` and `Dog`. They implement the `feed(...)` method from Pet. The closest I came to, is using ENUM:
Pet.java:

```
public abstract class Pet {

    public enum FoodType {
        DRY,
        WET,
        RAW;
    }

    public abstract void feed(FoodType foodType);
}
```

Cat.java:

```
public class Cat extends Pet {

    public void feed(FoodType foodType) {
        switch (foodType) {
            case DRY:
                System.out.println("Feeding this cat dry food.");
                break;
            case RAW:
                System.out.println("Feeding this cat raw food.");
                break;
            case WET:
                System.out.println("Feeding this cat wet food.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Dog.java:

```
public class Dog extends Pet {

    public void feed(FoodType foodType) {
        // implementation similar to feed() in Cat.
    }
}
```

App.java:

```
import pets.Dog;
import pets.Pet;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog01 = new Dog();
        dog01.feed(Pet.FoodType.DRY);
    }
}
```

But I don't like that, since ENUMS are static by default `FoodType` can be accessed from anywhere in project. Without creating a `Cat` or `Dog` object, i can call `Pet.FoodType.DRY` from anywhere. Preferebly it should be associated only with an object that inherits from Pet, eg:

```
Dog dog01 = new Dog();
dog01.FoodType.DRY; // do smth with this
```

Comment: I think this is considered bad practice, enums are good because they can be accessed from anywhere without creating an instance.

Comment: @devgianlu it does not have to be ENUM. Please suggest a better practice. Thank you.

Comment: This is already good practice, there's no change to make. You need an instance anyway to call the feed method.

Comment: Preferebly, I should not be able to see FoodType without creating Cat or Dog object. This should not be alowed: 
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Pet.FoodType.DRY);
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have declared FoodType as public. Please replace that with protected and this issue will be resolved.

```
protected enum FoodType
```

Alternatively to resolve this issue probably we can implement that as business logic

````
public abstract class Pet {

    protected String[] foodType = new String[]{"RAW","DRY","WET"};

    protected final String RAW_FOOD_TYPE = "RAW";
    protected final String DRY_FOOD_TYPE = "DRY";
    protected final String WET_FOOD_TYPE = "WET";

    public abstract void feed(String foodType);

    public String getRawFoodType()
    {
        return RAW_FOOD_TYPE;
    }

    public String getDryFoodType()
    {
        return DRY_FOOD_TYPE;
    }

    public String getWetFoodType()
    {
        return WET_FOOD_TYPE;
    }

}


public class Cat extends Pet {

    public void feed(String foodType) 
    {
        if(foodType.equals(DRY_FOOD_TYPE))
        {
            System.out.println("Feeding this cat dry food.");
        }
        else if(foodType.equals(RAW_FOOD_TYPE))
        {
            System.out.println("Feeding this cat raw food.");
        }
        else if(foodType.equals(WET_FOOD_TYPE))
        {
            System.out.println("Feeding this cat wet food.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid foodtype");
        }

    }
}


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat01 = new Cat();
        cat01.feed(cat01.getDryFoodType());

    }
}

```
````

Comment: Making the ENUM protected just limits access to it from within same package. It does not make it accessible via instance of Dog or Cat.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use enums only for this?. Can't we inplement that as business logic for feed method.

Comment: As it is mentioned already, no, ENUMS is just an example, not mandatory. It can be any solution.

Comment: I have modified my answer just now. See if this resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

So usally it should be fine to have public enum in practise for this. But to answer your question yes it is possible by modifying the structure a bit. So the constants here could be as `enum` or as `private final string` both would be fine.

Taking this case for enum, declare it as protected. Then create a method which will return the enum value inside the `Pet` class itself , which is essentially wrapping this in a getter.

```
    public FoodType getFoodType(String foodTypeStr){
        return FoodType.valueOf(foodTypeStr);
    }
```

This will make sure only instance variables of child classes can invoke it. Hence you can do something like this,

```
dog01.feed(dog01.getFoodType("DRY"));
```

This can be made protected and ovveriden in child if needed.

Comment: Are you declaring FoodType as public here?

Comment: Its mentioned in the answer its protected, the returned value is for self consumption , so this works.